# How Do you get AnkhSVN to work with VisualSVN Server?

Tags: svn, ankhsvn, visualsvn-server

I'm looking for the easiest free SVN implementation I can find.

I downloaded and installed VisualSVN Server - pretty easy.
Installed TortioseSVN - pretty easy - both work together.
Installed AnkhSVN, I can't get it to connect to the repository on the VisualSVN Server.

Is there anything special I need to do to get AnkhSVN to talk to the VisualSVN Server?

Answer (score 7):

To add a solution to SVN with Ankh, first setup the repo in VisualSVN.  Then go to Visual Studio and open the solution.  In the solution explorer, right click on the solution name and click "Add Solution to Subversion."  You'll then be able to specifiy the repository to which it should be added, e.g., "https://1.2.3.4:8443/svn/myproject/".

If your solution is already in Subversion, Ankh should be able to pick up on it and provide you with status icons and right-click menu options in Visual Studio.

If want to browse your SVN repo in Visual Studio, go to View->Repository Explorer.  Then you should be provided a nonintuitive-looking little icon that will say "Add Repository" when you hover it.  Put in the address of your SVN repository, e.g., "https://1.2.3.4:8443/svn/myproject/".  You can then browse the repo and open the solution file from there.

Answer (score 1):

I have a repository in visualSVN.
I can see that repository with Tortoise.
However I can't connect to it with the 'repository explorer' feature of anhkSVN.

I thought I had read that there were some issues with anhkSVN using http/s - the repository on the server is at an https://server:8443/svn/reponame

I have been able to get anhkSVN to work with a different server using the svn:// protocol, but not with the VisualSVN-Server using the https: protocol.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what happened here, but I got it working.
I had uninstalled visual studio standard and installed Visual studio Pro (difference being that pro has the are to pick the source control provider, standard does not)

However, I doubt that was it - the Repository explorer was there in the old one.
Could very well be that I typed something in wrong. It appears after some fiddling that subversion may well be case sensitive when it comes to the url and folder path you use for the repository - So I could see having gotten that wrong on my prior tests.

Comment: Subversion is indeed case sensitive

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [Simplified Tools Options](http://blogs.msdn.com/saraford/archive/2008/07/11/did-you-know-how-to-turn-on-and-off-simplified-tools-options-257.aspx) was the cause that you weren't able to select a Source Control Provider?

Answer (score 0):

without a solution, should I be able to use the repo explorer to view an existing repository?

I am unable to connect to the repository using repo explorer - It errors/times out.
Thats why I thought I must be doing something wrong (ie - maybe AnkhSVN doesn't work with SSL, or the firewall treats this client differently?)

Joel, I'll try your steps to add a solution and see if that works - it could well just be a bug in the repository browser.

Answer (score 0):

I just set up a VisualSVN server, TortoiseSVN, & AnkhSVN on my Vista system.  Since it's an intranet, it's NOT a secure connection and uses port 8080 (VisualSVN Server Network properties).  I also use Subversion authentication and have "everyone" as read-only and have IIS7 running, so port 80 is unavailable.

I too was having similar problems, but could access the repository in my browser via "http://server-name:8080/" which takes me to http://server-name:8080/svn/.  To get to the repository in TortoiseSVN required using the url "http://server-name:8080/svn/" since everything else would throw an error.

This is also the url I use inside VS to access the repository.